# How Remove old dll in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, package

I removed old version Newtonsoft.Json and add new verion . when run program display this error in package.config
 `<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />`
and in web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

How I can remove completely old verion in visual studio ?

[image]

Comment: Open Solution explorer, expand references and remove all unwanted dlls.

Comment: My problem was not resolved with this solution !

Comment: edit oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.1.0"

Comment: My problem was not resolved with this solution !

Answer (score 0):

See if there is some remnant in your project.
In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the project and chose "Unload Project". Right-click again and chose "Edit...". Now you see an Xml for your project setup. See if it is calling the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may it help you

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Change newVersion into 7.0.0.1